# How to track multiple BackgroundworkerX.Runworkercompleted operations

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, background-process

I am trying to use a single handler to cover the end of multiple backgroundworker activities and cannot find a way to get the information about the specific backgroundworker using the backgroundworkercompleted event.
My code to catch the event is as below:

```
Private Sub BGx_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker3.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker4.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker5.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker6.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker7.RunWorkerCompleted, BackgroundWorker8.RunWorkerCompleted

    'Do work here based on completed Backgroundworker

    For BG = 1 To 8
        If Not DSWorkers(BG).IsBusy Then
            If DStatus(BG) = -2 Then : DStatus(BG) = -1 : End If
        End If
    Next

    Complete()
End Sub
```

There is nothing on the "Do Work Here" section because I do  not know how to capture and have been unable to find details of the backgroundworkercompleted event id.

Please - any pointers as to how I can identify the specific completed BackgroundWorker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all event handlers, the `sender` parameter is a reference to the object that raised the event, so you can access the actual `BackgroundWorker` that has completed its work via that.  If you need some data other than that, you assign it to the `e.Result` property in the `DoWork` event handler and get it back from the `e.Result` property in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  `e.Result` works for getting data out of the `DoWork` event handler much as `e.Argument` works for getting data in.

Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889) out for some examples of using `BackgroundWorker` objects, including passing data out using `e.Result`.  You might also like to checkout my own [`BackgroundMultiWorker` class](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?632939), which basically combines the functionality of multiple `BackgroundWorker` objects into a single `BackgroundMultiWorker` object.  It identifies each task using a token.

EDIT:

Here's an example that may help with this issue and your task in general:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly resultsByWorker As New Dictionary(Of BackgroundWorker, BackgroundWorkerResult)
    Private ReadOnly rng As New Random

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'The NumericUpDown is used to select the index of a BackgroundWorker to cancel.
        With NumericUpDown1
            .DecimalPlaces = 0
            .Minimum = 0
            .Maximum = 9
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Create 10 BackgroundWorkers and run them.
        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim worker As New BackgroundWorker

            resultsByWorker.Add(worker, New BackgroundWorkerResult)

            AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf workers_DoWork
            AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf workers_RunWorkerCompleted

            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

            worker.RunWorkerAsync()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim index = Convert.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value)
        Dim worker = resultsByWorker.Keys.ToArray()(index)

        If worker.IsBusy Then
            'Cancel the BackgroundWorker at the specified index.
            worker.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub workers_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim worker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        'Do work for a random number of seconds between 10 and 20.
        Dim period = rng.Next(10, 20 + 1)

        For i = 0 To period
            If worker.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Return
            End If

            'Simulate work.
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next

        'The work was completed without being cancelled.
        e.Result = period
    End Sub

    Private Sub workers_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim worker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        Dim result = resultsByWorker(worker)

        If e.Cancelled Then
            result.WasCancelled = True
        Else
            result.Result = CInt(e.Result)
        End If

        Dim workers = resultsByWorker.Keys.ToArray()

        If Not workers.Any(Function(bgw) bgw.IsBusy) Then
            'All work has completed so display the results.

            Dim results As New List(Of String)

            For i = 0 To workers.GetUpperBound(0)
                worker = workers(i)
                result = resultsByWorker(worker)

                results.Add($"Worker {i} {If(result.WasCancelled, "was cancelled", $"completed {result.Result} iterations")}.")
            Next

            MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class BackgroundWorkerResult
    Public Property WasCancelled As Boolean
    Public Property Result As Integer
End Class
```

Here is that example reworked to use a single instance of the `BackgroundMultiWorker` is linked to instead of multiple instances of the `BackgroundWorker` class.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents worker As New BackgroundMultiWorker With {.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True}
    Private ReadOnly results(9) As BackgroundWorkerResult
    Private ReadOnly rng As New Random

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'The NumericUpDown is used to select the index of a BackgroundWorker to cancel.
        With NumericUpDown1
            .DecimalPlaces = 0
            .Minimum = 0
            .Maximum = results.GetUpperBound(0)
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Create 10 BackgroundWorkers and run them.
        For i = 0 To results.GetUpperBound(0)
            results(i) = New BackgroundWorkerResult

            worker.RunWorkerAsync(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim index = Convert.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value)

        If worker.IsBusy(index) Then
            'Cancel the BackgroundWorker at the specified index.
            worker.CancelAsync(index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub worker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker.DoWork
        'Do work for a random number of seconds between 10 and 20.
        Dim period = rng.Next(10, 20 + 1)

        For i = 0 To period
            If worker.IsCancellationPending(e.Token) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Return
            End If

            'Simulate work.
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next

        'The work was completed without being cancelled.
        e.Result = period
    End Sub

    Private Sub workers_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles worker.RunWorkerCompleted
        Dim result = results(CInt(e.Token))

        If e.Cancelled Then
            result.WasCancelled = True
        Else
            result.Result = CInt(e.Result)
        End If

        If Not worker.IsBusy() Then
            'All work has completed so display the results.

            Dim output As New List(Of String)

            For i = 0 To results.GetUpperBound(0)
                result = results(i)

                output.Add($"Task {i} {If(result.WasCancelled, "was cancelled", $"completed {result.Result} iterations")}.")
            Next

            MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, output))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class BackgroundWorkerResult
    Public Property WasCancelled As Boolean
    Public Property Result As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for that - had been trying to use the e.result method but this fails if the backgroundworker was cancelled by the user. This s really the problem since I need to do work for the specific backgroundworker IF it was cancelled  by the user. I have added some  code to pick up an external tag and check ALL background tasks but it would be easier if there was some id info I could get from the sender parameter .. there might be something but I have not been able to find ot.

Comment: I reread your comments and I am sure the answer is in the sender parameters but how do I call them?... I will need a pointer on this since I have not found the info through my searches or  by reading the syntax docs.

Comment: See my edit for a complete code example.  I'll rejig that to use a `BackgroundMultiWorker` too.

Comment: I have added the `BackgroundMultiWorker` example.